# Ros topic echo doesn't show on multi-computer setting

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the tutorial on http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines.
I tried setting up 3 computer running ROS. Let's call them RobotComputer, MasterComputer, NodeComputer.

MasterComputer can see topics of RobotComputer, and command sent on them move the robot as expected.
Calling rostopic list on NodeComputer, I can see topics from RobotComputer. The problem is : rostopic echo on MasterComputer shows data, it doesn't on NodeComputer.

I created 2 separated network, with MasterComputer acting as a gateway. I won't be able to put them all on the same network.
Is there a way to make this work? Am I missing an obvious step?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/379396/ros-topic-echo-doesn%27t-show-on-multi-computer-setting/) by [Vic](https://answers.ros.org/users/68202/vic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2021-06-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) on 2021-06-02**:
Is it related to this: https://answers.ros.org/question/371773/

**Comment by [Vic](https://answers.ros.org/users/68202/vic/) on 2021-06-02**:
Sadly no, because topics I send on the NodeComputer doesn't show up either on MasterComputer. Plus, the unanswered question deals with services, I am only trying to read and write on a topic for now.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-06-02**:
There is no difference in services, messages or actions when it comes to networking setup. So anything you read about any of those applies to your problem as well.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-06-02**:\

> I created 2 separated network, with MasterComputer acting as a gateway. I won't be able to put them all on the same network.

please provide *much* more information about your network setup. IPs, subnets, routers involved, is NAT enabled? What sort of network(s)? Etc.

At the very least bi-directional IP (TCP and perhaps even UDP) traffic between all involved hosts on both networks must be working. If that works, checking DNS settings and the various `ROS_` environment variables on all hosts must be configured correctly.

> I followed the tutorial on http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/Mul.... I tried setting up 3 computer running ROS

then please show *what* you configured on which host.

**Comment by [Vic](https://answers.ros.org/users/68202/vic/) on 2021-06-03**:
Network between RobotComputer and MasterComputer : ethernet LAN (just an ethernet cable between the 2 computers). IP adresses are 198.168.100.40 (RobotComputer) and 198.168.100.50 (MasterComputer).
Net mask is 255.255.255.0
Both device ping each other.

Network between NodeComputer and MasterComputer : ethernet LAN (just an ethernet cable between the 2 computers). IP adresses are 10.0.0.2 (NodeComputer) and 10.0.0.1 (MasterComputer).
Net mask is 255.255.255.0
Both device ping each other.

I exported ROS_MASTER_URI and ROS_IP and ROS_HOSTNAME
Focusing on the "faulty" network :
On NodeComputer,

```
ping 10.0.0.1
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.0.0.1:11311/
export ROS_IP = 10.0.0.2
export ROS_HOSTNAME = 10.0.0.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Should had RTFM better.

One of ROS requirement in Networking :
"There must be complete, bi-directional connectivity between all pairs of machines, on all ports. "
Not the case on my network. Will try again after buying a switch

---

Originally posted by [Vic](https://answers.ros.org/users/68202/vic/) with karma: 71 on 2021-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-06-03**:
Did you use a NAT router?

**Comment by [Vic](https://answers.ros.org/users/68202/vic/) on 2021-06-03**:
No, all computers are connected on the main one by Ethernet cable, on differents ethernet cards. Thus, RobotComputer is unpingable from NodeComputer, which break ROS Network requirements

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-06-03**:
That sounds like something which IP routing could solve for you.

You're probably aware, but a switch would only work if you place everything in the same subnet.

**Comment by [Vic](https://answers.ros.org/users/68202/vic/) on 2021-06-11**:
Yes. The actual underlying issue of the subnet : we are using 2 robots with lots of components that were'nt made to work in fleet. On the same network, there would have been tons of collision for topic because all the component share name and IP. We putted a switch linked to the second ethernet card of the computer inside the robot, everything is now reachable by everyone, problem solved